# Joining separated Date and Hour to create a single Date() Object

Tags: swift, timestamp

I have this app written in swift where I get a future date and a future hour (As Unix Timestamp) separately and I want to turned them into one Date() Object so I can converted to Unix Timestamp.

If you now another way to converted directly to Unix Timestamp feel free to post.

Comment: You mean `Date` object, not `Calendar`.

Comment: “a future date and a future hour separately” ... how are you getting these? Strings? Numeric values? Separate `Date` objects?

Comment: date as Date() with format "dd-MM-yyyy" (I Also have the unix timestamp saved) and the hour as Int (1 - 24) @Rob

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "date as `Date()` with format 'dd-MM-yyyy'". `Date` objects don't have a "format". Only string representations (such as converted by `DateFormatter`) of `Date` objects have a "format". I'm going to assume that you started with a string of the format "dd-MM-yyyy" and that you want to convert that to a `Date` and that you then want to then get another `Date` object for that date at a specified hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may give you some ideas on how to accomplish what you want:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let currentDate = Date()

// Random future date, 1 month from now
let futureDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
let futureDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: futureDate)

// Random hour
let futureHour = 2

// Use your future date and your future hour to set the components for the new date to be created
var newDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate)
newDateComponents.year = futureDateComponents.year
newDateComponents.month = futureDateComponents.month
newDateComponents.day = futureDateComponents.day
newDateComponents.hour = futureHour
newDateComponents.minute = 0
newDateComponents.second = 0

// Create a new date from components
let newDate = calendar.date(from: newDateComponents)!

// Convert new date to unix time format
let unixTime = newDate.timeIntervalSince1970

print(newDate) // 2018-03-06 02:00:00 +0000
print(unixTime) // 1520301600.0
```

Note that in a real project you should avoid force unwrapping (i.e. using '!').

Answer (score 0):

If you have a date string in the form of `dd-MM-yyyy`, you can convert that to a `Date` object like so:

```
let string = "02-06-2018"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")   // this is only needed if string is always gregorian but you don't know what locale the device is using
guard let date = formatter.date(from: string) else {
    // handle error however you'd like
    return
}
```

Or, if you already have a `Date` object, then you don't need the above. But regardless, once you have a `Date`, you can then get a `Date` by setting the hour, minute, and second as follows:

```
let hour = 14  // 2pm
guard let result = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date) else { 
    // handle error however you'd like
    return
}
```